# Preventing Duplicate DB Reads

Tags: storage

If an extrinsic performs the same storage read twice (e.g. same storage map read with same key), under which conditions is the duplicate DB read optimized away by substrate's storage layer? Where are such guarantees documented?

Answer (score 1):

There is a storage overlay in place to improve efficiency. The majority of the service will utilize `System::Number`. Querying the database every time would be inefficient.

For more information, please refer to the following resources:

- [Clarity on storage read/write caching](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2574/clarity-on-storage-read-write-caching)
- https://docs.substrate.io/build/runtime-storage/
- https://www.shawntabrizi.com/assets/presentations/substrate-storage-deep-dive.pdf